# wcf return an XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xmldocument

I have a WCF service where Im building up a block of XML using an XmlWriter.  Once complete I want to have the WCF return it as an XmlDocument.

But if I have XmlDocument in the [OperationContract] it doesnt work:

```
[OperationContract]
XmlDocument GetNextLetter();
```

The WCF test utility gives:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using .Net 3.5 then you can try returning [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) instead - this implements [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), which is the missing ingredient needed to make it work with DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 14):

append xmlserializer on what you did in the operational contract

```
[OperationContract,XmlSerializerFormat]
XmlDocument GetNextLetter();
```

this will do it !

Answer (score 3):

The DataContractSerializer can serialize XmlElement instances. So just return the DocumentElement property of your XmlDocument instance. See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Don't send the XMLDocument, because you can reconstruct it on the other end.

You should probably send down the string that you want, or construct a business object which can be serialized to XML and transmit that.

Have a look at XSD.exe tool with the .net framework if you have an XSD and you want to make a business object from it which can be serialized.

Comment: xsd is more XmlSerializer focused - WCF would often use DataContractSerializer...

Comment: I guess I've been tainted by legacy XML systems :(.  If you're in a greenfield WCF layout then datacontract would probably be a good way to go.