# 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, serialization, appfabric, xmldocument

I am using AppFabric caching in my C# application. I am attempting to cache a XmlDocument but getting the following error:

> Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why not just store the XML as a string, rather than as an serialized XmlDocument class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: wcf return an XmlDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964870/c-wcf-return-an-xmldocument)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, and solved it by marking the property/field that contained the XML document as NonSerializable.