# WCF Client error in creating a proxy for a WCF service

Tags: wcf, xmldocument

I have WCF service which accepts a xmldocument and returns a xml document, Below is the interface code

```
namespace CreateLabelWS
{

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://localhost/Create")]
public interface ICreateLabel
{
    [OperationContract,XmlSerializerFormat]
    [FaultContract(typeof(CustomException))]
    XmlDocument CreateLabelRequestIntoDB(XmlDocument Request);
}


[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class CustomException
 {
    [DataMember()]
    public string Title;
    [DataMember()]
    public string ExceptionMessage;
    [DataMember()]
    public string InnerException;
    [DataMember()]
    public string StackTrace;
    [DataMember()]
    public int RowsInserted;
 }        
}
```

But when I create a proxy for this and try to access CreateLabelRequestIntoDB from the client application, I found that to be exposed as Xelement type rather than XMLDocument. Could anybody help me here and also tell me if there's any error in my code

Dins

Comment: @JohnSaunders Could you please provide your suggestions om this please

Comment: possible duplicate of [wcf return an XmlDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964870/wcf-return-an-xmldocument)

Comment: John Saunders... we invoke thee to answer this question... come hither from thou's realm of perfect knowledge...